# Print Variable Json PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON

```
$data= '[
    {
        "opa": "maam",
        "clik": "7026981995",
        "pt": 123,
        "aaab": [{
            "ttt": "1.22",
            "tt": [{
                "aaa2": 1.2277,
                "aaa122": 19811225
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        "opaa": "maam1",
        "clik1": "7026981995",
        "pt1": 123,
        "aaa11": [{
            "ttt1": "1.222",
            "tt1": [{
                "aaa1": 1.2277,
                "aaa3": 19811225
            }]
        }]
    }
]'
```

I need to print it on the screen, just as it is in the variable, I tried

`echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`

But, a pile is printed, not being readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about `<pre>`, which is the "[preformatted text element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre)"?

```
die('<pre>'.print_r(json_decode($data), true).'</pre>');
```

this would also work (which I'd assume is what you've meant):

```
die('<pre>'.$data.'</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

It is already in json format. Just do:

```
echo $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. change the code to:

   print_r(json_decode($data), true)
2. Get JSON formater extension for chrome to prettify the json.